# ¿Como podria filtrar datos de una tabla de acuerdo al valor seccionado de un select junto con fechas?

Tags: javascript, html, c#, .net, programación-funcional

Esta es una tabla con diferentes select, y quisiera que al momento de hacer una busqueda desde ellos me arroje informacion en una tabla y asi mismo desde un boton limpiar me borre  lo buscado, lo que tengo en los selects[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Por favor toma en cuenta en como se debe preguntar https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask y las imágenes las puedes poner directamente.